# Terraform AWS Provider: array of ECS task placement constraints?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I'm using terraform 0.10.7 and AWS Terraform provider version 1.7.

In my terraform for creating an ECS task, I would like to be able to use multiple ECS placement constraints. Looking through the Terraform documentation, I see only examples of using a single constraint, but everything seems to indicate that this is possible. (Example: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/e77ce9a5fca5b2a3e1138f5df86e87170ac8e89a/aws/resource_aws_ecs_task_definition.go)

My most recent attempt looks like:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task" {
  family                = "${var.service_name}"
  container_definitions = "${var.container_definitions}"
  task_role_arn         = "${var.task_role_arn}"
  placement_constraints {
    count = "${var.placement_constraint_count}"
    type = "memberOf"
    expression = "${element(var.placement_constraints, count.index)}"
  }
}
```

In the passed-in tfvars, I have various things declared, including:

```
var.placement_constraint_count = 1
var.placement_constraints = [ "attribute:adsk.max-container-disk-space-gb not_exists or attribute:adsk.max-container-disk-space-gb == 100"]
```

(It's a custom attribute, not relevant to the problem at hand.)

This results in: 
* Errors: [placement_constraints.0: invalid or unknown key: count]

Looking through the Go source code for the schema of a placement constraint (https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/e77ce9a5fca5b2a3e1138f5df86e87170ac8e89a/aws/resource_aws_ecs_task_definition.go) - it's a TypeSet with a maximum of 10 elements, each of which has a 'type' and an 'expression'.

So... what's the proper way to say all that?

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: I get the impression that you need to repeat the entire `placement_constraints {...}` block for each constraint - something you won't be able to do with a `count` argument.  There doesn't look like there's a way to attach these outside of the main `aws_ecs_task_definition` resource either, so I'm not sure you can dynamically vary these in the way you want in Terraform itself - you may need to pre-process your Terraform script files to actually put multiple `placement_constraints` in them where needed.

Comment: I feared that was true, and was hoping to avoid that fate. I'll listen for more answers, in the hope that I'm not forced to agree with you. :)

Comment: Here's a variation that I was able to get to work with a single placement constraint: placement_constraints[ "${var.placement_constraint}" ] where var.placement constraint itself evaluates to "{ "type": "memberOf", "expression": "some-constraint" }". But then how do I expand that to multiple values?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Do you want a reusable module that can accept 0-N placement constraints? Any reason why you wouldn't just make each caller specify the placement constraints in a single cluster query? I'm not aware of anything that would force you to need multiple placement constraints rather than just defining a query with multiple `and`s in it.

Answer (score 3):

## Clarification

I ran up your Terraform snippet in my sandbox just now to check things out, and the given error is sound if a little terse:

```
Error: aws_ecs_task_definition.task: placement_constraints.0: invalid or unknown key: count
```

The reality is that `placement_constraint` does **not** support a `count` attribute.

Taking the `count` line out of the `placement_constraint` block stopped the error from occurring.

The [schema in the code you linked](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/e77ce9a5fca5b2a3e1138f5df86e87170ac8e89a/aws/resource_aws_ecs_task_definition.go#L117) only specifies `type` and `expression`, and there is no allowance for `count`.

Defining multiple constraints requires multiple instances of the `placement_constraint` block in the Terraform template.

## Alternative suggestion

For your purposes, I would use something along these lines:

### terraform.tfvars

```
placement_constraints = [
  "attribute:one == 1",
  "attribute:two == 2",
  "attribute:three == 3",
]
```

### ecs_task.tf

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task" {
  container_definitions = "${var.container_definitions}"
  family                = "${var.service_name}"
  task_role_arn         = "${var.task_role_arn}"

  placement_constraints {
    expression = "${element(var.placement_constraints, 0)}"
    type       = "memberOf"
  }

  placement_constraints {
    expression = "${element(var.placement_constraints, 1)}"
    type       = "memberOf"
  }

  placement_constraints {
    expression = "${element(var.placement_constraints, 2)}"
    type       = "memberOf"
  }
}
```

Yes, it is repetitive and ugly.

No, Terraform is not a feature-complete v1.0 tool just yet.

I run into limitations like this one all the time with my clients and projects.

On the plus side, the [upcoming `for` and `for-each` loops in v0.12](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each) should help with situations like this.

Hope that helps!

---

I ran all of this with the following from `terraform version`:

```
Terraform v0.11.7
+ provider.aws v1.28.0
```